# How docker clients filters token list

Tags: docker

I want to understand how it filters the token in background.

When I run `docker images ls` for checking the list of images, it won't work; but when I run `docker images`, it gave me the list of images.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to run `docker image ls` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it would be great if you can explain me how docker  filters the token